# JEE Architectural question: Service can inject Service? Or Service can inject only Dao?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, architecture, ejb

Here is a architectural problem while using Dao and Service and Controller:

Suppose that:
In DAO layer, there are DAO Classes called: Dao1, Dao2, ...

In Service Layer, there are Service Classes called: Service1, Service2, ...

In Controller Layer, there are Controller Classes called: Controller1, Controller2, ...

Service1 need to inject Dao1, and **Service2**

Controller1 need to inject Dao2, Service1 and **Controller2**

Does this architecture follow the JEE principales? Is there any issue?

It is better tp say that: Service can inject only Dao, and Controlleur can inject only Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, JEE does not mention/recommend the design patterns. JEE defines the set of APIs across different areas such as transactions, jdbc, jax-rs and so on and the implementation of these APIs is provided by different vendors. Thus JEE standards help develop an enterprise application but they do not dictate any design principles. So I guess that your question is whether this architecture follows good design patterns and if there is any issue.

Ideally as per your second question, a controller must not inject a dao class. A controller must only call services and the services should inject dao classes and call their methods. This design provides loose coupling between controller, service and dao layers. This way, if the signature of a dao class method changes, the controller layer is untouched and only service layer needs to change.

Generally speaking, most designs try to achieve loose coupling and high cohesion as much as possible.

Hope this helps!